# PC/SC driver for smart card simulation. How to get started?

Tags: driver, smartcard, pcsc

I need to develop a Windows driver that would emulate plugged smart card reader (so that Windows would show it on the list of plugged devices) and a smart card into them. Instead of this it would read/write data from/to file according to specific protocol.

What approach should I take to emulate a smart card reader and card?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I understand correctly, but I assume you want to redirect I/O instead of a smart card to file. This would only make sense for non-smart i. e. memory cards, since as soon as intelligence on the smart card side is needed, a file approach must fail. Memory cards are unfortunately out of scope for PCSC resource manager, so I suspect your requirements are contradicting.

Comment: @guidot Disagree there, you do have to implement the processor card APDU handling of course, but a lot of ISO 7816-4 is specifying a file system structure for processor cards. It is perfectly possible to create a driver that simulates this and uses a file for background storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took a bit of searching, but I got it back. Please have a look at the article "An UMDF Driver for a Virtual Smart Card Reader". It's an excellent written article and actually provides the code as well.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134010/An-UMDF-Driver-for-a-Virtual-Smart-Card-Reader

In short, it uses the User-Mode Driver Framework to create a "virtual" smart card driver. A simulator could be easily based on this.

Note that implementing the behavior of the simulated smart card depends on your needs.

Comment: This article is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!